# ItemControl not binding objects correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, wcf-binding

I have a XAML page that contains an ItemControl tag (the application uses the MVVM light framework):

```
<ItemsControl MinWidth="100" MinHeight="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Options}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Margin="10,0">
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

This control has an item source that is a list of Option objects.  The data template for this item control is as follows:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Sales:Option}">
     <local:SalesOptionButton d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have a view model that is associated with the SalesOptionButton control which is as follows:

public class SalesOptionButton
    {
        private string _name;
        private Option _Option;

```
    public ICommand SelectedOptionButtonCommand { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetStructPropertyValue(ref _name, value); }
    }

    public Option Option
    {
        get { return _scriptOption; }
        set { SetPropertyValue(ref _scriptOption, value); }
    }

    public SalesScriptOptionButton(ScriptOption option)
    {
        Option = option;
        Name = option.OptionText;
    }

    protected override void RegisterForMessages()
    {
        SelectedOptionButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(OptionButtonSelected);
    }

    private void OptionButtonSelected()
    {
        MessengerService.Send(ScriptOptionSelectedMessage.Create(ScriptOption));
    }

    protected override void SetDesignTimeInfo(){}
}
```

Here is the XAML for the Option Control:

```
<UserControl [INCLUDES]>
    <Button Height="25" Padding="1" MinWidth="100" Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding SelectedOptionButtonCommand}"/>
</UserControl>
```

What this does is, for every option that is in the datasource, a button is created.  These buttons should display the name of the option and, when the button is clicked, send a message to the main application that will process that click (set the chosen option).

The issue that I am seeing is that the buttons are being created but nothing else is being bound (There is no option name being displayed on the button and the button click is not working).  Can anyone give me an idea as to why this isnt working like I think that it should be?

Comment: where do you define the: `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Sales:Option}">`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the data template as a property of your items control.

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate={StaticResource OptionTemplate} .../>

<DataTemplate x:Key="OptionTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Sales:Option}">
     <local:SalesOptionButton d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Actually you shouldn't need to. They have specified the type and the ItemControl should pick up on that without needed to specify the template explicitly.

Comment: This does not work.  I get the following exception: Cannot find resource named 'OptionTemplate'. Resource names are case sensitive.

Comment: You may be right, but I find it's safer to be explicit.  I would like to see the definition of the *Options* property.

Comment: @Matt Burland: You are correct, it tells me that the name is negligible.  But if that is the case, then what is wrong with my code?

Comment: The Option property is on the viewmodel of the control that contains the button.  THe property looks like this: public ObservableCollection<Option> Options
        {
            get { return _scriptOptions; }
            set { SetPropertyValue(ref _scriptOptions, value); }
        }                                                                The SetPropertyValue simply does the property notification stuff

Comment: My bad, should be x:Key="OptionTemplate", not x:Name.

Comment: SetPropertyValue looks suspicious, there's no property name or lamba expression.  How does the notification get raised?

Comment: public virtual void SetStructPropertyValue<T>(ref T currentValue, T newValue, Action<T> extraFunction = null, Action voidActionAfterSetAction = null)
        {
            currentValue = newValue;

            PropertyHasChanged();

            if (extraFunction != null) extraFunction(newValue);

            if (voidActionAfterSetAction != null) voidActionAfterSetAction();
        }

Comment: @Phil: A little off-topic, but I can think of at least one case where you wouldn't want to be explicit and that's the case where you have a heterogeneous collection of object types and you have different templates for each of them. But, in this case, it certainly can't hurt.

Comment: @TheSheekGeek: I'm not familiar with mvvm-light, but what's with the [INCLUDES] bit in your UserControl? Aside from that (and assuming the UserControl is actually your SalesOptionButton) I don't really see a problem. If it is correctly producing the right number of buttons then it is recognizing the collection and recognizing the type (in order to pick up the right template). The only thing left is, as Phil pointed out, the question of notifications which I assume is what SetPropertyValue is supposed to do handle.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to decipher your post when bits and pieces of the code appear to be missing. You say:

> This control has an item source that is a list of Option objects. The data template for this item control is as follows:
>
> ```
> <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Sales:Option}">
>     <local:SalesOptionButton d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
> </DataTemplate>
> ```

You haven't shown us your `Option` class - only your `SalesOptionButton` class. Presumably, your `Option` type has some property that yields the associated `SalesOptionButton` instance? If that's the case, then your data template is wrong here:

```
<local:SalesOptionButton d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
```

You're setting the `DataContext` of the `SalesOptionButton` to the `Option` instance, not to the `SalesOptionButton` instance. I'm guessing (and I have to) that you want something like this:

```
<local:SalesOptionButton d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" DataContext="{Binding SalesOptionButton}"/>
```